# How to read request body and query params in next 13's API with app router in route.ts file?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Did not found any solution here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route.

Comment: Check the declare class `NextRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NextJS 13, with `route.ts` File Conventions in `app` dir, we can read query params and request's body with this:

```js
import url from "URL";

export async function POST(request: Request) {

  const requestBody = await request.json(); // To read request data

  const queryParams = url.parse(request.url, true).query;  // To read query params

  // Returning the query params & body
  return NextResponse.json({
    requestBody,
    queryParams,
  });

}
```

Comment: So ugly, but I guess this is the best way to read query params??

Answer (score 24):

In NextJS 13, in **app/api/route.js** you can use URL class to read the params

```js
export async function GET(req){
    const {searchParams} = new URL(req.url);
    const param = searchParams.get("/*Your param key here*/");
    console.log(param)
}
```

To get req body

```js
export async function POST(req){
    const body = await req.json()
    console.log(body)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately, this seems really unintuitive, would encourage NextJS to adopt a model similar to Express, or better yet merge APIs so we don't have like 5 different `Request` model apis to keep track of.

Answer (score 21):

For anyone looking to grab the dynamic **route parameter** like I was, it's in the second argument.

`/api/something/[id]/route.ts`

```
export async function GET(req, { params }) {
  const id = params.id;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way I believe now is to simply use

```
req.nextUrl.searchParams
```

```
export const GET = async (req) => {
    // Req Body
    const requestBody = await request.json();


    // Search Params
    const searchParams = req.nextUrl.searchParams;
    const foo = searchParams.get('foo');
}
```

If you check the `NextURL` type def there is a lot of good stuff in there.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#url-query-parameters

Answer (score 1):

It's declare class NextURL.

So we can use `req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('xyz')` XD.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can read the request body and query parameters for the Nextjs 13 app directory and Typescript:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'


// Inside app/api/route.ts
// This will create end point GET http://localhost:3000/api

// Test this like http://localhost:3000/api?name=Meera

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {

    const {searchParams} = new URL(request.url);
    const name = searchParams.get("name");

    return NextResponse.json({name})
}

// This will create end point POST http://localhost:3000/api

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) { 

    try {
        const json = await request.json();

        
        return NextResponse.json(json)
    
    
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return new Response(null, { status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request" });
      }


}
```